# What is the method that updates the stock.move of the next stock.picking step on clicking validate button?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

I have been searching through the [code base](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/14.0) for the method that updates the `stock.move` of the next `stock.picking` step on clicking validate button. I cannot find where exactly it is. I want to inherit the method to change some behaviors.

Anyone know which method in which model for this?

Comment: You mean when they are connected to each other by either `move_dest_ids` or `move_orig_ids`?

Comment: @CZoellner I am yet to fully understand the whole structure of stock/move models. I mean when validate button is clicked in PICK step, some records in Operation tab in PACK (next step) are changed. I know that there are conditions for the changes; so, I am looking for the method.